# How does a program handle an interruption with several threads and signals?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

Imagine I have a program with a main function that creates several threads. In each thread I redirect the `CTRL + C` interruption (`SIGINT`) to a `functionA` via `signal(SIGINT, functionA)` and in the main process I redirect the same interruption to a `functionB` (`signal(SIGINT, functionB`).

When the program is running and the interruption `SIGINT` is sent, what will the program do?
It will execute `functionA` in all threads then `functionB` in the main process?

Comment: [Strictly speaking](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p7): "Use of this function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal handler action (SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL, or a handler function) is a per-process property, not a per-thread property.

This means that if say different threads use [sigaction()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to set the same signal action, then the latest one wins.

Furthermore, if you have multiple threads that do not block the signal, the kernel simply chooses one (at random, basically) to use to deliver the signal.  That is, it is only delivered once, not once per thread.